# NSTextView width different on Mojave vs Catalina after zooming

Tags: macos, nstextview, nsscrollview

My document's NSTextView is enclosed in a NSScrollview subclass (to manage zooming). The zoom level change is managed by this NSScrollView subclass here:

```
- (void)setScaleFactor:(CGFloat)newScaleFactor {
    if (newScaleFactor != self.scaleFactor){
        [self setMagnification:newScaleFactor];
        self.scaleFactor = newScaleFactor;
        CGFloat scaler = newScaleFactor / self.scaleFactor;
        [self.documentView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(scaler, scaler)];
        NSLayoutManager* lm = [self.documentView layoutManager];
        NSTextContainer* tc = [self.documentView textContainer];
        [lm ensureLayoutForTextContainer:tc];

    }
}
```

On Mojave, everything behaves normally (zoom factor between 75% and 200%). When the document content cannot be displayed totally in width (window too small), I can scroll horizontally without any problem.
On Catalina, when I scroll horizontally (and sometimes vertically) there are unwanted scrolls (for example back or forward to the cursor, sometimes to the left or to the right). After hours of tests/analysis I noticed only one different behaviour of the scrollview between the two MacOS versions. On Mojave, the maximum NSTextView width is not modified by the zoom, and scroll to the right is constrained. On Catalina, I can scroll indefinitely to the right (tested until a 125 inches width on the ruler).

What can explain such a difference of behaviour between the two MacOS versions on such basic objects (NSTextView, NSScrollView)? What did I missed?

Comment: Your code looks overcomplicated. Is `[self.delegate.textView superview]` the same as `self.contentView` and is `self.delegate.textView` the same as `self.documentView`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the code necessary to accomplish a zoom in the scroll view. But the trouble on Catalina persists.

Comment: I noticed that on Mojave, after going through this code, the frame of self.documentView is unchanged. On Catalina, the frame is changed (and the width has been multiplied by a big factor)

Comment: Well, after resetting and re-saved the document with zoom level to one (was saved before with a x2 factor), and  making clean build, the problem has gone… I don't know what happened but it worked, thanks Willeke!